# Part function: can we use pattern for part functions?

Tags: assignment, argument-patterns

Can we use some patterns for the arguments of `Part` functions?

```
vec = Array[v,10];
rndmi = RandomInteger[100,10];

v[i_Integer] = rndmi[[i]]
```

Then I got a "Part::pspec" error.

Can we use some patterns for the arguments of `Part` functions or not?

Comment: `v[i_Integer] := rndmi[[i]]` [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I understood the difference between = and := but I I thought = is sufficient in this case. Why do I need "delayed" in this case.

Comment: `v[i_Integer] = rndmi[[i]]` computes `rndmi[[i]]` first, *exactly as you wrote it, with a symbolic `i`*, then assigns the result to `v[i_Integer]`.  This will fail the same way as evaluating `rndmi[[i]]` on its own would.  `v[i_Integer] := rndmi[[i]]` makes the assignment without evaluating `rndmi[[i]]` first.

Comment: @Kuba I think that answer needs improvement ... I don't think it is easy to understand for a beginner.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quite ambiguous answer to your question is: "*Yes, you (and we) can!*". Sometimes we might simply let *Mathematica* complain or turn complaints off using [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)...

So note this:

```
rndmi = RandomInteger[100,10]; (* immediately assigns a list of 10 numbers to rndmi *)

v[i_Integer] = Quiet @ rndmi[[ i ]]
```

> {99, 93, 50, 56, 83, 40, 53, 62, 18, 90}[[i]]

That output tells you a great deal about why there has been a complaint, and also why it might still work:

- There is an immediate assignment ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) to the Pattern `v[i_Integer]` which leads to an error in the current case, since `i` is a symbol without an OwnValue (cf. [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html))
- `rndmi` never shows up, since it is immmediately replaced by its `OwnValue`
- The `OwnValue` for the Pattern might yet give good results for concrete values

Look at the definition for v:

```
?v
```

> v[i_Integer]={99,93,50,56,83,40,53,62,18,90}[[i]]

And do try this:

```
v[1]
```

> 99

So, it does work but may not be the best choice for what you want. But again, *Mathematica* is rather a very logical tool. :)

Comment: As you know, I'm a beginner and not sure what you intended to say... Sorry, that's my problems. Anyway, to circumvent the error, is it a simple and natural way to use delayed set := to define?

Comment: @Taki Bessho Yes, using `:=` avoids the problem. You need to read about DownValues and OwnValues - it is essential.